# jquery slide show - why does this code work?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, modulo

I was in the middle of coding a slideshow in javascript using jquery, when I ran into something that was doing what my several lines of code was doing in a couple lines.

Problem is, I don't comprehend how it works so I can modify it.

```
var imgs = [
        'image1.jpg',
        'image2.jpg',
        'image3.jpg'];
        var cnt = imgs.length;

    $(function() {
        setInterval(Slider, 4000);
    });

    function Slider() {
    $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
       $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    }
```

This is the line that gets me:

```
[(imgs.length++) % cnt]
```

I'm reading that as

```
3+1 % 3 = 1
```

Now every time it executes, none of that code appears to be modifying any of the variables. 
`cnt` will always equal `imgs.length` (3), `imgs.length++` doesn't actually modify it, it just adds one for that single execution, correct?

So matter how many times it executes, it will always be `imgs[1]` yet when I execute the code, it runs properly through all the array objects.

**EDIT:**

I simply added `alert(imgs.length);` and confirmed that `++` does actually change the variable, but it still doesn't make sense to me.

The first run, `imgs.length = 4` after ++. `4 % 3 = 1` so it should run array object `[1]` not `[0]`?

Second run, `5 % 3 = 2`

Third run, `6 % 3 = 0`

etc etc.. but it shouldn't ever reset. However, if I put a `alert(imgs.length % cnt);` it only returns 0, 1, 2 than it resets.

Why?

Comment: In regards to your edit, see my code sample. On running x++, the value of x is modified *after* returning its original value. To return the modified value, you would use ++x.

Comment: Also, 6 % 3 = 0. It's not a subtraction operator; it's modulus - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: @Matchu is right, `6 % 3 = 0` not `3` (the remaining part after dividing `6` by `3` is `0`)

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing that out! I'm way too tired today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the return value of `imgs.length++` is 3 therefore 3 % 3 = 0 but `imgs.length` will be `4` and the `imgs` array will contain `4` items.

try it in console:

```
var x = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
x.length++
=> 3
x.length++
=> 4
x.length++
=> 5
x
[1, 2, 3, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

so every time `imgs.length++` is called itt will append one item to the array. so not a nice code but short :)

**EDIT**: the why is easy to answer, in the start it contains `cnt` number of elements, so the code will step on every image and the starts from the beginning of it. so if the `imgs` array contains `5` items it will step through the `5` items and starts from the beginning.

the only problem with this code, that the array will be increased every time and the memory will be eaten by the browser.

Comment: the easy fix for the code should be to create a counter in the beginning and increment that one.

   `var cnt = counter = imgs.length;`

and then `imgs.length++` can be replaced with `counter++`

Comment: so it's actually adding more objects to the array? I understand now. cnt caches the original imgs.length and never changes as imgs.length changes. makes sense now...

Comment: Google Chrome's console doesn't show the other undefineds at the end. It's not clear to me if the undefined's are actually being stored as array values, or if Firefox is just showing them to you for presentation purposes. Either way, I'm not a fan of the implementation.

Comment: maybe you can try `JSON.stringify(x)`

edit: no, you cannot it works differently in Safari and in Firefox, so sad!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you're aware that `imgs.length++`, if it were applied to any other variable, would be adding one to it, modifying the original variable.

```
var x = 1;
alert(x++); // alerts 1
alert(x); // alerts 2
```

Sure enough, that's what's going on.

The script increments the length of the `imgs` array on every run, so it moves from 3 to 4 to 5 to 6, etc. I'm not an expert on Javascript internals, so I'm not sure if that has any effect on performance, but if you understand that `length` is, in fact, a writable property, it all makes sense.

Comment: Good point in pointing out a subtle case that might not be obvious, in that the first alert would display 1 and not 2, because the increment happens after the value is returned

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure in javascript but every other language I know `imgs.length++` is the same as saying `imgs.length = imgs.length + 1` so that should be getting modified.

I'd consider it a "clever trick" that should be documented if used at all.  <strike>It kinda breaks the semantics of what length means, so while logically correct to a computer it doesn't quite make sense in relation to the property name</strike>

So I guess it actually does change the length, but I still wouldn't recommend using it without documenting it.  A more clear method would be to declare a new var `i = 0` and replace `imgs.length++` with `i++`, because although it doesn't probably matter in this case, if you're doing anything else with the array, the length is now probably not what you expect it to be.

**Regarding the edit:**
6 % 3 is 0 not 3.
Modulo (in programming, slightly different in purely math term) means divide and take the remainder.
6 / 3 = 2 with a remainder of 0.
7 / 3 = 2 with a remainder of 1.
8 / 3 = 2 with a remainder of 2.
9 / 3 = 3 with a remainder of 0,

Comment: so that actually modifies it? I was thinking it was taking `imgs.length` and adding 1 to it, not actually changing `imgs.length` itself by adding 1.

Comment: As @Matchu points out, length is a writable property of an array in javascript, so yes it does change the length.  If it wasn't writable (not sure if there's such a thing as readonly property in JS) it would probably give an error.  x++ is just a shortcut for saying x = x + 1

Answer (score 0):

(imgs.length++) % cnt

will cause the images to loop through every image, over and over.

the percentage sign (%) in JavaScript means it uses Modulus (division remainder) operator.

Examples:

- 0 % 3 = 0
- 1 % 3 = 1
- 2 % 3 = 2
- 3 % 3 = 0
- 4 % 3 = 1
- 5 % 3 = 2
  etc...

Comment: I think the OP understands that much, and is confused as to *why* imgs.length++ is even increasing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, every 4:th second that the function Slider runs it expands the array, so 
you get:

```
3+1 % 3 = 1
4+1 % 3 = 2
5+1 % 3 = 0
```

and so on  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be more readable in the future, I would personally suggest you change your code to something like this:

```
var imgs = [
    'image1.jpg',
    'image2.jpg',
    'image3.jpg'];
var i = 0;

$(function() { // This is a shortcut for $(document).ready();
    setInterval(Slider, 4000);
});

function Slider() {
   $('#imageSlide').fadeOut("slow", function() {
      i = (i+1) % imgs.length;
      $(this).attr('src', imgs[i]).fadeIn("slow");
   });
}
```