# jQuery slideshow code does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a slideshow for the following markup using jQuery like this: 
I want a border (as specified for .active css in my stylesheet) to be displayed around any image thumbnail that I click. Also the a preview should be displayed above (for #previewImg) when clicked. 

[image]

```
<div id="gallerypreview">
    <img id="#previewImg" alt="preview for image" src="gallery/autumn1.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="gallerythumbs">

    <div class="gallerythumb">
        <img src="gallery/autumn1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="gallerythumb">
        <img src="gallery/autumn2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="gallerythumb">
        <img src="gallery/autumn3.jpg">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS for `.active`:

```
.active{
    border:2px #000 solid;
}
```

I don't know why my jQuery code does not work:

```
<script>
    /*Begin Photo Gallery Code*/
    var images = ['gallery/autumn1.jpg', 'gallery/autumn2.jpg', 'gallery/autumn3.jpg'];

    function loadImage(src) {
        $('#previewImg').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).html('<img src="' + src + '" />').fadeIn('slow');

        });
    }

    function goNext() {
        var next = $('.gallerythumb>img.active').next();
        if (next.length == 0)
            next = $('.gallerythumb img:first');

        $('.gallerythumb').removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active');
        loadImage(next.attr('src'));
    }

    $(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            $('#previewImg').append('<img src="gallery/' + images[i] + '" />');

        }


        $('.gallerythumb img').click(function() {
            $('.gallerythumb img').removeClass('active');

            loadImage($(this).attr('src'));
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });

        loadImage('gallery/' + images[0]);
        $('.gallerythumb img:first').addClass('active');

        setInterval(goNext, 4000);
    });
</script>
```

Besides spoiling my layout, this also loads the first image in #previewImg and when I click either of images (.gallerythumb>img), #previewImg does not change to currently clicked image. Also, automatic swapping of images between 4000ms interval does not work. 

Any tips will be appreciated. I have to deliver this project very soon :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a useful piece of code on a SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094184/jquery-slide-show-why-does-this-code-work). Then I changed the code as follows and it worked. Finally I have slideshow that automatically switches between thumbnail images previewing one at a time. Also when each thumbnail is clicked, it gets a border and is displayed above (preview):

```
<script>
                    $('a#tazeha').on("click",function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#row1-content').load(this.href);

                    });
                    $('a#montakhab').on("click",function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#row1-content').load(this.href);

                    });

                </script>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="row1-center"></div>
        <div id="row1-left">
        <script>
        var imgs = [
        'gallery/autumn1.jpg',
        'gallery/autumn2.jpg',
        'gallery/autumn3.jpg'];
        var cnt = imgs.length;

        $(function() {
      setInterval(Slider, 4000);

    });

    function Slider() {
    $('#previewImg').fadeOut("slow", function() {
       $(this).attr('src', imgs[(imgs.length++) % cnt]).fadeIn("slow");
       if(imgs.length++ % cnt==2) $('.gallerythumb>img').removeClass('active');

       $('.gallerythumb>img').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#previewImg').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
        }
        );


    });
    } 



        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the hash in your HTML. 'id="#previewImg' should be 'id="previewImg'. Also, where is the element with the id 'gallery' referenced by '$('#gallery>img.current')'? I also don't see you ever assigning the class 'current' to an element.

I'd suggest a careful line-by-line review of your code.